# Error when trying to launchIOSDevice using NetBeans Gluon Plugin / Apple Free Provisioning

Tags: netbeans, ios-provisioning, gluon-mobile

I've successfully run a simple Gluon application using NetBeans 8.1, Gluon plugin, javafxports 1.0.7, Mac OS X 10.11.1, Xcode 7 using Gluon Mobile - Single View Project. When I try to run on my connected iPhone 6 using launch | launchIOSDevice, however, I'm having errors with the provisioning. Error message is Execution failed for task ':createIpa'.

> No signing identity found matching '/(?i)iPhone Developer|iOS Development/'

I setup an identically named project on Xcode and ran it on my connected device. I verified that I have Provisioning Profiles and Signing Identities defined for my project (Xcode | Preferences | Accounts). I verified that the Xcode project Bundle identifier is the same as the ios CFBundleIdentifier as defined in the Default-info.pllist file. I tried defining ios properties iosProvisioninProfile and iosSignIdentity in the build.gradle file. This gave different error messages, but the build still failed.

Has anyone successfully run a NetBeans/Gluon-Mobile app using Apple's Free Provisioning on a connected IOS device? I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but need help figuring it out!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it with a free provisioning profile. I did it with an apple developer account, but here are the steps I've taken maybe it can help you:

1. Get accepted as an apple developer (not your case)
2. Go to XCode, click code->preferences
3. Go to the accounts tab
4. click the plus button to add an account. Add your account.
5. Click file->new project->single view application
6. Put whatever product name and organization identifier (it doesn't matter)
7. Choose whatever place you want to store the project
8. For any issue that arises like "no non-expired provisioning profiles were found", click fix issue.
9. Connect ios device and run app.
10. start gluon ios gradle task (for instance 'launchIOSDevice')
    It will take a lot of time the first time. In the end it may give you a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Put in your gradle JVM settings: '-Xmx2000M'.
11. Start ios gradle task again.

You can also check: http://docs.robovm.com/getting-started/provisioning.html#limitations for free provisioning advise, but you probably already have.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed list. I gave up trying with the Free Provisioning and went ahead with my developer account. Everything works great. Also, you only have to create an XCode project once per device, which is a significant advantage over the free provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free provisioning account. You just need to add a couple of lines to the build.gradle file in the iOS settings:

```
iosProvisioningProfile = 'xxxx'
iosSignIdentity = 'yyyy'
```

The ProvisioningProfile is the file name of the provisioning provisioning profile you created in xCode. Just right click, and choose "Show in Finder". Just copy the file name (you don't need to copy the "mobileprovision" extension.

The SignIdentity (yyyy) you can get with by opening a terminal and entering the following command:

```
security find-identity -v -p code signing
```

Look for the line that contains "iPhone Developer: " line and copy everything in the quotes

Answer (score 0):

You need a apple developer account (the free variant works fine). Then you create a xCode project that matches your Gluon project so that:

`Product Name` in your xCode project is the same as your Gluon project's `Project Name`

and...

`Organization Identifier` is the same as as your Gluon project's `Package Name`

Then it should work fine. I have made this in Eclipse and later in Netbeans - and it have worked in both places.

**Edit:** By using this way however you have resign your app (around every 24h) - which means opening the project (that you created before that is being similar to your Gluon project) - letting xCode revalidate the project with your developer id. If you do not do this you will experience that your app doesn't open, (but it will be shown/exist among other opened apps - when you double tap the home button on iPhone).